# What is a another way to describe a union stronger than the parts?

Tags: expressions

I am looking for a beneficial way to describe the merger of two companies where the sum of the two is stronger than the two halves - where each brings something the other needs.

Comment: "Synergy" is good. Another idea: "Sometimes the whole is greater than the sum of its parts."

Comment: "Synergy" is good (see @LPH, below). Another idea: "Sometimes the whole is greater than the sum of its parts."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The idea you are seeking is perfectly contained in the word "*synergy*".

> [investopedia](https://www.investopedia.com/terms/s/synergy.asp)
>
> Synergy is the concept that the combined value and performance of two companies will be greater than the sum of the separate individual parts. Synergy is a term that is most commonly used in the context of mergers and acquisitions (M&A). Synergy, or the potential financial benefit achieved through the combining of companies, is often a driving force behind a merger.